# Is there a way to upload file in database instead of in filesystem via webform?

Tags: 6, webforms, files

When files are uploaded via [webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform), the attachment is stored in filesystem. Is there a way to store the attachment in database blob field?

Answer (score 1):

You could read the field and write the contents in the database. This could be done in a custom submit handler to the webform form.

Comment: Any pointer about "custom submit handler"?

Comment: `$from['#submit']` see form reference at api.drupal.org and `hook_form_alter`